# Remove the package alsa from the Yocto Build

Tags: yocto, alsa, imx8

My requirement -- was to Remove the package alsa from the Yocto Build. So

I just tried to Remove the ALSA Packages from the Yocto Build.

I followed same procedure as you stated

1. MACHINE_FEATURES_remove = "alsa" on your machine.conf
2. poky.conf, used DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "alsa".

But it removed some of the alsa packages in rootfs looks good, these alsa-lib, alsa-conf still exists in the tmp/deploy/licenses/machine/licence.manifest file

Can any one suggest me the way to Remove that from Yocto Build.

Comment: Which Yocto are you working on? In latest version, it updated the override operator `_` with `:`.  So `MACHINE_FEATURES:remove = "alsa"` and `DISTRO_FEATURES:remove = "alsa"` should be used. And they could be set in local.conf for development.

Comment: Still these packages exists in the license.manifest file.

PACKAGE NAME: alsa-conf


PACKAGE NAME: alsa-lib

PACKAGE NAME: alsa-ucm-conf

Comment: You should check which packages installed inside your image depend on alsa, and either remove such packages or each definition of the dependency one by one, you can analyze package dependencies for your image using ` bitbake -g <your-image>` and then looking at the generated task-depends.dot file

Answer (score 0):

As @ah008a said, you could check the dependencies for your image such as core-image-sato with cmd `bitbake -g core-image-sato`. Then check the file **task-depends.dot**.

The other way is to check the dependency by starting the image. Append following to local.conf:

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"
```

then build and start the image. Check alsa related packages and try to remove them:

```
root@qemumips:~# rpm -qa | grep alsa |xargs rpm -e --test                            
error: Failed dependencies:                                                                                                                                                 
        alsa-ucm-conf is needed by (installed) libasound2-1.2.8-r0.mips32r2                                                                                                 
        alsa-conf is needed by (installed) libasound2-1.2.8-r0.mips32r2               
        pulseaudio-module-alsa-card is needed by (installed) pulseaudio-server-16.1-r0.mips32r2                                                                             
        pulseaudio-module-alsa-sink is needed by (installed) pulseaudio-server-16.1-r0.mips32r2                                                                             
        pulseaudio-module-alsa-source is needed by (installed) pulseaudio-server-16.1-r0.mips32r2                                                                           
        alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf is needed by (installed) pulseaudio-server-16.1-r0.mips32r2
```

Then try to remove the dependencies recursively such as:

```
root@qemumips:~# rpm -e --test libasound2
```

Finally find that

```
pulseaudio-server is needed by (installed) packagegroup-core-x11-sato-base-1.0-r33.qemumips
```

Check the recipe `meta/recipes-sato/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-x11-sato.bb` and distro feature `pulseaudio` should be removed too. So set in local.conf:

```
MACHINE_FEATURES:remove = 'alsa'
DISTRO_FEATURES:remove = 'alsa pulseaudio'
```

Then there is no alsa related packages installed to the image **core-image-sato**.